# Difference between /usr/bin/strings and gstrings from binutils?

Tags: bash, homebrew

I'm running macOS BigSur 11.6.5 (20G527)  and I've installed binutils with homebrew and it provides a gnu version of `strings`.

It has different output for the same file, e.g /bin/ls

```
%> strings /bin/ls | head
I9H0
J8I9H8
H9J0
O8H9J8
I9H
J(I9H(
H9J
O(H9J(
I9H@
JHI9HH

%> gstrings /bin/ls | head
__PAGEZERO
__TEXT
__text
__TEXT
__stubs
__TEXT
__stub_helper
__TEXT
__const
__TEXT
```

I'm wondering how mac strings works? Why does it produce different output?

Comment: From the [man page of the mac version](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/strings/): _strings looks in all sections of the object files except the (__TEXT,__text) section_ . This clause is not present in the man page of the gnu version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various versions of `strings` have existed. Most of them simply look for a certain number (four or more) of printable ASCII characters, and decide, without context, that it's found a human-readable "string." This appears to be the case with the supplied `strings` command.

GNU `gstrings` appears to be much smarter. I don't have `gstrings` installed, but it seems to be using a heuristic that is a bit smarter than merely looking for printable ASCII characters. (Some 40 years ago, in a C programming class I took, one of our assignments was to write a better version of `strings`. It wasn't very difficult!)

To better understand the discrepancy, I suggest you use a different utility, `hexdump`.

`hexdump -C /bin/ls` will show you the hexadecimal codes in a table for every byte in the file, with ASCII interpretations of them an the end of each row:

```
00000000  cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01  03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  13 00 00 00 10 07 00 00  85 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.......... .....|
00000020  19 00 00 00 48 00 00 00  5f 5f 50 41 47 45 5a 45  |....H...__PAGEZE|
00000030  52 4f 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |RO..............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  19 00 00 00 28 02 00 00  |............(...|
00000070  5f 5f 54 45 58 54 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |__TEXT..........|
00000080  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........P......|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........P......|
```

As you can see, the same "real" human-readable strings shown on the right are also in the `gstrings` output.

So, the simple answer is, GNU `strings` does a better job than the default BSD `strings`.